# getElementsByTagName for parsing xml file works only in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, xml-parsing, getelementsbytagname

I want to go through an xml file to find the "marker" simple tags and read their "lat" and "lng" attributes to show on the gmap. Opposite to what I've found on tenths of threads, GetElementsByTagName IS working ONLY in IE8 and NOT in IE9, Firefox or Chrome. The code is part of a joomla component (so not mine) and I don't want to change it completely.

```
  var request = GXmlHttp.create();
  request.open("GET", $mapfile, true);

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      var xmlDoc = GXml.parse(request.responseText);
      var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      alert(markers.length);
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
        var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
      }
    }
  }
```

Nothing complicated in the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<markers>
    <marker lat="53.0" lng="48.0"/> 
    <marker lat="55.0" lng="32.0"/> 
    <marker lat="42.0" lng="21.0"/> 
    <marker lat="-3.0" lng="-79.0"/> 
    <marker lat="10.0" lng="-66.0"/>
</markers>
```

Although my code reads correctly the xml (request.responseText contains the xml text), the markers.length is zero. It's even more weird that the same code was working fine when my site was on another server. Should I look something related on the...(?) server settings?

I tried without .documentElement, no difference. I even saved my code file in utf-8, so also the "marker" text is at the same encoding, but no.

I am not experienced on javascript and it's not easy for me to try with jQuery.

Thank you for any reply.

Comment: What is this "GXmlHttp" thing? *edit* - oh Google Maps sorry

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED! 
I don't know why, but the first line of the xml file was causing the problem. Removed and everything works perfect. 
Does anyone understand why?